# class constructor matching, why didn't the move constructor called here?

Tags: c++

I'm recently learning about move constructor, and I met a strange problem.
I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class a
{
public:
    a() { printf("default\n"); }
    a(const a& aa) { printf("const lr\n"); }
    a(a& aa) { printf("lr\n"); }
    a(a&& aa) { printf("rr\n"); }
    a(const a&& aa) { printf("const rr\n"); }
};

a foo()
{
    return a();
}

void func(a& a) {
    printf("func lr\n");
}

void func(a&& aa) {
    printf("func rr\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("a1: ");a a1;
    printf("a2: ");a a2(a1);
    printf("a3: ");a a3(std::move(a2));
    printf("a4: ");a a4(foo());
    printf("a5: ");a a5(std::move(foo()));

    func(foo());
}
```

The output is:

```
a1: default
a2: lr
a3: rr
a4: default
a5: default
rr
default
func rr
```

All is good except for a4. I expect that the return type of `foo()` is a rvalue. I think the call of `func()` at last has proved that. So why doesn't the move constructor called when constructing a4? And at the same time, it is called when constructing a5.

Comment: A typical case of copy elision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's probably because of [`copy_elision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy- and move- construction of class object:
>
> 1. In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object:
>
> `T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x`
>
> 2. In a function call, if the operand of a return statement is a prvalue and the return type of the function is the same as the type of that prvalue:
>
>    ```
>    T f() { return T{}; }
>    T x = f();         // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>    T* p = new T(f()); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize *p
>    ```

Your situation falls under the second case.